# TextView filling up EditText below it

Tags: android

Ran into a strange bug where `TextView`'s (login_message) text is filling up `EditText`'s (username) text that is below it.

Attaching my layout file.

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        tools:showIn="@layout/activity_login">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/login_error"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="invisible"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/login_message"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/username"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Enter your username here"/>
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/password"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:hint="Enter your password here"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="login"
            android:text="Login"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Not a member? Register"
            android:onClick="goToRegistration"/>


    </LinearLayout>
```

How do I debug / fix this.

Comment: Try adding weights to each View inorder to overcome overlapping.

Comment: Can you share a screenshot?

Comment: add screenshot pls

Comment: I have checked your code and its looking fine in preview in Android Studio. Kindly share screen shot.

Answer (score 0):

Try to give some margin to username from top.

```
android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    >
    <TextView
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/login_error"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="invisible"/>

    <TextView
        android:padding="10dp"

        android:text="dddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd"
        android:id="@+id/login_message"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

    <EditText
        android:padding="10dp"

        android:id="@+id/username"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Enter your username here"/>
    <EditText
        android:padding="10dp"

        android:id="@+id/password"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:hint="Enter your password here"/>
    <Button
        android:padding="10dp"

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="login"
        android:text="Login"/>
    <Button
        android:padding="10dp"

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Not a member? Register"
        android:onClick="goToRegistration"/>


</LinearLayout>
```